# display the content of a numeric array php, single number type

Tags: php, arrays, echo

Asking a simple question,

```
$a = [array(]2, 4, 6, 8);

     echo $a;
```

why return Array in html page and not the numbers?

Comment: because of its array see this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that's not the way to declare an array in php.  You declare it like this:

```
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
```

or like this:

```
$a = [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ];
```

Secondly, "echo" prints strings.  An array is not a string.  If you want to print the contents of an array you can use:

```
print_r($a);
```

or:

```
var_dump($a)
```

or:

```
foreach($a as $number)
{
   echo($number.' ');
}
```

or:

```
echo(implode(',', $a));
```

or:

```
echo($a[0]);
echo($a[1]);
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to display
  print_r($a)